# Motivating mathematics(particularly algebraic number theory) through historical problems.

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-number-theory, math-history

Most mathematical textbooks start a subject by going backwards, historically. They will define the terms that were invented to solve a problem in their polished form and then use these definitions and structures to solve a problem towards the end of the book, if at all. This is conceptually clear but often obscures motivation.

One glaring example of this is Galois theory. The original solution of the problem progressed through steps that barely resemble the final product. While some motivation is given, I have not found any book that goes through the historical steps that led to galois theory.

I would like any articles or books that motivate subjects through their historical roots/problems. I think what I am really asking for is a book/article that focuses on problems used to generate theory rather than the construction of a general theory that is later used to solve problems. For instance, I would like a book/article that explains what Lame's approach to fermat's last theorem was and how it failed and led to ideals.

I am particularly interested in books that focus on algebraic number theory, but other fields are very welcome too.

Comment: Try simply doing Putnam or similar contest problems. The Miklos Schweitzer ones are particularly good. Or for something less demanding, try the many subject area "problem books" now available. If you have a problem to solve, that motivates understanding the machinery that is needed to solve it. The reason few books/courses are done that way is that few people can cope with hard problems. Most people can only see maybe one step ahead, so they need an avalanche of definitions and lemmas before they can do anything. But it is all a question of balance.

Comment: I look forward to recommendations on Alg Geom. I just bought Gortz and Wedhorn, which was highly recommended, but turns out to be turgid :)

Comment: Unknown Quantity, John Derbyshire

Comment: Also posted (and closed) at MO, http://mathoverflow.net/questions/180454/motivating-mathematicsparticularly-algebraic-number-theory-through-historical --- and, Paprika, by now you should know that it was  **your** responsibility to provide this link.

Comment: Since this question is four year old, do you now recommend any such books on Abstract Algebra/Complex Analysis/Real Analysis/Algebraic NT/Analytic NT for this exact same purpose ?

Comment: @almagest How can doing Milkos Schwetizer problems (those are pretty difficult btw) help ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might be interested in Edwards' book which does Algebraic Number Theory by way of Fermat's Last Theorem --- here's a [review](http://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.bams/1183548007). And here's a [review](http://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/pdf/upload_library/22/Ford/Neumann407-411.pdf) of Edwards' book on Galois Theory.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, they look very interesting.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if this is what you had in mind, but Stillwell's [*Mathematics and its History*](http://www.springer.com/mathematics/history+of+mathematics/book/978-1-4419-6052-8) presents an historical overview of mathematics by actually talking about the problems examined during a particular period - using modern notation and with lots of nice exercises.

Also, while not about algebraic number geometry, two books co-authored by Gerhard Wanner might fit the bill: [*Analysis by its History*](http://www.springer.com/mathematics/analysis/book/978-0-387-94551-4) and [*Geometry by its History*](http://www.springer.com/mathematics/geometry/book/978-3-642-29162-3).

Answer (score 1):

Half a year later, I have gone through quite a few books and Edward's book from Gerry's answer was very good. I also really like "Primes of the form $x^2+ny^2$".

Comment: I should have also mentioned Hadlock, Field Theory and its Classical Problems, in the Carus Mathematical Monographs series of the MAA.

Comment: I have had the pleasure of going through that book, it was very excellent!